# Find how many times every word is repeated in db

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

Am using drupal to manage my content. I want to search all my contents title and body and find how many times each word is repeated in the whole contents.

It may be by an sql query, but I have no experience with sql.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please show us your effort?

Comment: then search and count the word using query

Comment: This will not be easy for you if you have no experience with sql, i suggest that you read the basic sql syntax specifically grouping

Comment: Here is some php code I have.     SELECT id, title, body FROM table  $items = array();  $result = mysql_query($sql); while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {     $items = $row['title']+$row['body']; $final_results = explode(" ",$items[]); while($final_results) {  INSERT INTO tags VALUES ($final_results[i]) } }

Answer (score 0):

This code searches the body field and *ALL* fields of *ANY* Content Types for a specific string.  You can run it via command line.  Say you save it as "fieldsearch.php", you can then run it as:

php fieldsearch.php "myStringForWhichToSearch"

You need to fill in your connection data and database name.  It outputs the array of matching nodes but you can format that output into anything you'd like (I recommend csv).

```
<?php


//Set Parameters here
$env = "dev"; // Options [dev|prod] - Defaults to dev

$prodConnection = array(
                        "host" => "",
                        "user" => "",
                        "pass" => ""
                        );


$devConnection = array(
                        "host" => "",
                        "user" => "",
                        "pass" => ""
                        );

//Use the selected env settings
if($env == "prod"){
  $connection = $prodConnection;
} else {
  $connection = $devConnection;
}



function getTables($con, $database){
  //Get the set of field tables
  $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $database";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

  if (!$result) {
      echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
      echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
      exit;
  }

  $tables = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
      $tables[] = $row[0];
  }

  mysqli_free_result($result);

  return $tables;
}

function getFieldTables($con,$database){
  $allTables = getTables($con, $database);

  $fieldTables = array();
  foreach($allTables as $key => $table){

    if( isFieldTable($table) ){
      $fieldTables[] = $table;
    }
  }

  //add the common tables
  $fieldTables[] = "field_data_body";
  $fieldTables[] = "field_data_comment_body";

  return $fieldTables;
}

function isFieldTable($table){
  //echo $table . "\n";
  if( stripos($table, "field_data_field") !== FALSE){
    return TRUE;
  }
}

//Set the search term here:
if (array_key_exists(1, $argv)) {
  $searchString = $argv[1];
}
else {
  die('usage: php fieldsearch.php "search string"' . "\n");
}

  $databaseName = "myDatabaseName";

  $outArray = array();

  //Connect
    $con=mysqli_connect($connection['host'],$connection['user'],$connection['pass'],$databasePrefix.$databaseNum);
  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  //getFieldTables
  $fieldTables = getFieldTables($con, $databaseName);

  //Query each field tables data for the string in question
  foreach($fieldTables as $key => $table){

    //get Field value column name
    $valueCol = str_replace("field_data_field_", '', $table);

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 
                                      entity_id 
                                  FROM
                                      $table
                                  WHERE 
                                    field_" . $valueCol . "_value
                                  LIKE 
                                    '%$searchString%';");

    if($result){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $dataArray[$table][$row['entity_id']]['nid'] = $row['entity_id'];
      }
    }
  }

  //Add the body table
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 
                                    entity_id 
                                FROM
                                    field_data_body
                                WHERE 
                                  body_value
                                LIKE 
                                  '%$searchString%';");

  if($result){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $dataArray['field_data_body'][$row['entity_id']]['nid'] = $row['entity_id'];
    }
  }

  var_dump($dataArray);
```